# Solving a 5x5 pentomino with only certain shapes

Tags: tiling, polyomino, packing

I have a physical Pentomino puzzle lying around, which contains 2 F pieces, one Y piece, one T piece and one W piece. The area into which the squares are supposed to fit in is just a little under 6 units in both directions. What layout am I supposed to use here? Is the solution to rotate a specific layout?

Answer (score 10):

Hint

> Yes, and since 'normal' and 45 degrees will not work, you will need to be creative.

Solution:

> [image]

Comment: If I didn't screw up my maths this should fit into a square with side length 5/2\sqrt(5)=5.59....

Comment: It is 2sqrt5 + 1/sqrt5+ 2/sqrt5 (5.814)

Comment: I get $\frac52 \sqrt{5} + \frac1{2\sqrt{5}} = \frac{13}{5} \sqrt{5}$ which matches Retudin's value.